# Replace mysql user shell in /etc/passwd

Tags: shell, users, passwd

I am searching a way to replace the mysql user shell configuration in /etc/passwd from command line as there are multiple servers where I want to disable the shell for mysql user.

Actual

```
mysql:x:498:498:MySQL server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/bash
```

Desired

```
mysql:x:498:498:MySQL server:/var/lib/mysql:/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Dont use sed! see `chsh` or `usermod`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't modify `/etc/passwd` with `sed`. Use the tools provided for interfacing with that file instead.

In this case, `chpass`/`chsh`, or possibly the more general `usermod`.

On most systems:

```
$ sudo chpass -s /sbin/nologin mysql
```

or

```
$ sudo chsh -s /sbin/nologin mysql
```

would work.

You don't want to edit `/etc/passwd` with `sed` (or with `vim`/`emacs`), and *definitely* not with `sed -i`.

User @JdeBP reminds me about the `vipw` utility in the comments below.  This is a special command, much like `visudo`, that lets you edit the `/etc/passwd` while taking care of file-locking etc. It also does consistency/syntax checking of the saved file before installing the new password file in place of the old one. Refer to the manual for `vipw` on your system for more information.  This is the only safe way to edit the passwords file by hand.

Also note that on *some* Unix systems, the default login shell is set by other means than through the password file.  On OS X, for example, ordinary users don't even have an entry in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @SuyashJain The way to modify `/etc/passwd` is not the `sed` way. Don't try to use `sed` to modify important system files that have tools specifically designed to interface these files. Do not teach others the wrong way to manage their systems.

Comment: I do agree, completely

Comment: You must log out and log back in to see this change.

Comment: This answer could be made even better by mentioning `vipw`, by noting (since the question is a general one that didn't specify one operating system) that it is `pw usermod` rather than `usermod` on FreeBSD/PC-BSD, and by mentioning that on the BSDs `/etc/passwd` is not even the right file to be modifying *anyway*.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks for reminding me about `vipw`. I'm ignoring `usermod` since it is fairly chimeric between systems. Could you please clarify your last point though, as it doesn't apply to OpenBSD.